# How to change a label of AuthenticationForm called in the LoginView and how to use another form in LoginView ? (Django 3.0)

Tags: python, django, forms, templates, loginview

I'm learning Django 3.0 and I'm actually using the `django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView`

Here is my `views.py` file:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
    template_name = "blog/loginview.html"
```

And here is my `urls.py` file:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpattenrs = [
   url(r'^login/$', views.CustomLoginView.as_view(), name='login')
]
```

I know I could put everything in the url without making my own view but I wanted to test it.

Here is my template:

```html
<h1>Connection with LoginView</h1>

<form method="POST" action=".">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Connect" />
</form>
```

Everything works perfectly, but on my page, I can see the default labels from the `AuthenticationForm` used by default by the `LoginView`.
These are `Username:` and `Password:`.

Now here are my questions:

- Is it possible to change the labels to `foo` instead of `Username:` and `bar` instead of `Password:` from the template and keep the `{{ form.as_p }}` in the template? Or even better, changing the labels from the `CustomLoginView`?
- Is it possible to use a custom form for the `CustomLoginView`? Or even better, directly in the `LoginView`?

Comment: If you have another question - please ask a new one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to change the labels but it will be in `forms.py` file, here is an example:

```
class ChildForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Child_detail
        fields="__all__"
        labels={
            'username':'foo',
            'passowrd':'bar',
        }
```

Comment: I tried what you explained and I updated my question. Maybe there is something I didn't understand ?

Answer (score 1):

I overwritten the `AuthenticationForm` and used it in the overwritten `LoginView`:

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

class CustomAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def __init__(self, request=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(request=None, *args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].label = 'a cool label'
        self.fields['password'].label = 'another cool label'
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

class MyLoginView(LoginView):
    template_name = "login.html"
    authentication_form = CustomAuthenticationForm
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('login/', MyLoginView.as_view(template_name= 'login.html'), name='login'),
]
```